# Move constructor with memcpy

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

I have a struct that i want to be non copyable, only movable, but as it contains a lot of POD, writing move constructor would be long and forgetting a variable would be hard to debug. Example:

```
struct myStruct{
    int a,b,c,d;
    double e,f,g,h;
    std::complex<double> value1,value2;

    std::unique_ptr<Calculator> calc;

    myStruct(){}
    myStruct(const myStruct &)=delete;
    myStruct(myStruct && other);
};
```

What would be the problems with this kind of move constructor:

```
myStruct::myStruct(myStruct && other){
    std::memcpy(this,&other,sizeof(myStruct));
    other.calc.release();
    calc->rebind(this);
}
```

What problems could I face and is this well defined?

Comment: `unique_ptr` is going haywire for sure.

Comment: It will probably will have to references to single memory object so both would call delete on the same memory, but it should be avoided with `release();`

Comment: the point is that it's not guaranteed, `memcpy`ing non PODs is UB regardless of the precautions you may take.

Comment: @UldisK: `release` might (or might not) make the undefined behaviour less disastrous, but it won't make it any better defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimal change is just to group the trivially-initialized members together, so you can `memcpy` them easily:

```
struct myStruct{
    struct {
        int a,b,c,d;
        double e,f,g,h;
        std::complex<double> value1,value2;
    } pod;

    std::unique_ptr<Calculator> calc;

    myStruct(){}
    myStruct(const myStruct &)=delete;
    myStruct(myStruct && other);
};

myStruct::myStruct(myStruct && other){
    std::memcpy(&pod,&other.pod,sizeof(pod));
    other.calc.release();
    calc->rebind(this);
}
```

Note `std::complex` is a *literal type*, which should be safe to put into the pod member. If you add any other member objects of class type, you'll have to verify yourself that they're safe to memcpy.

---

A better implementation would, as Jonathan Wakely pointed out, sidestep the concerns about pod and non-pod (or literal, and trivially-initialized) members. Instead, group members by whether you want them copied or moved:

```
struct myStruct{
    struct {
        int a,b,c,d;
        double e,f,g,h;
        std::complex<double> value1,value2;
    } val;

    std::unique_ptr<Calculator> calc;

    myStruct(){}
    myStruct(const myStruct &)=delete;
    myStruct(myStruct && other);
};

myStruct::myStruct(myStruct && other)
  : val(other.val)              // copy the value types
  , calc(std::move(other.calc)) // and move the reference types
{
    calc->rebind(this);
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `memcpy(&pod, &other.pod, sizeof(pod));` over `pod = other.pod;`? (Answer: there isn't one)

Comment: Also you probably want `calc = std::move(other.calc);` instead of `other.calc.release();` because otherwise the object will be leaked and `calc->rebind(this);` will dereference a null pointer.

Comment: Both true - I just made the smallest possible change to the OP's existing code, and didn't even think about the rest.

Comment: Have a +1 now :) that new implementation is very nice and clean

Comment: So, judging from @JonathanWakely's comment, the first half of this answer is wrong. Is my understanding correct? If so, I'm happy to upvote this answer once the problematic approach gets removed.

Comment: The first half is the minimal change to fix the immediate specific problem - it isn't _wrong_, but deliberately doesn't improve the style of the original code. The second half is more like how I'd do it starting from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the default move Ctor:

```
myStruct(myStruct&& other) = default;
```

Comment: That's not going to do the same work with the `unique_ptr` that he is doing.

Comment: I was under the impression, that, as I have deleted the copy constructor, default move constructor should not be created.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Indeed; it will move the pointer, rather than doing some kind of undefined behaviour that probably results in a dangling pointer.

Comment: @UldisK: If you declare a copy constructor (deleted or otherwise) then the move constructor won't be generated implicitly. It can still be generated explicitly, like this.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I was referring to `calc->rebind(this);`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You're right, I didn't spot the back-pointer. That makes things nastier.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: After the recent edit I prefer [the accepted answer from @Useless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19790060/981959). The following is left to demonstrate an alternative approach that allows the move constructor to be defined as defaulted, but which is over-engineered compared to the accepted answer.**

Using `memcpy` is a bad idea. I might consider creating a helper type that does the non-trival work (moving the `unique_ptr` and rebinding the calculator) and use that in `myStruct`, so that its move operations can be defaulted:

```
struct RebindableCalc
{
  RebindableCalc();

  RebindableCalc(RebindableCalc&& r) noexcept : calc(std::move(r.calc))
  { calc->rebind(self()); }

  RebindableCalc& operator=(RebindableCalc&& r) noexcept
  {
    calc = std::move(r.calc);
    calc->rebind(self());
    return *this;
  }

  std::unique_ptr<Calculator> calc;

  myStruct* self();
};

struct myStruct : RebindableCalc
{
    int a,b,c,d;
    double e,f,g,h;
    std::complex<double> value1,value2;

    myStruct() = default;
    myStruct(myStruct&& other) = default;
    myStruct& operator=(myStruct&& other) = default;
};

inline myStruct* RebindableCalc::self()
{
  return static_cast<myStruct*>(this);
}
```

This will let the compiler generate the optimal code for the POD members, and still do the right thing for the `unique_ptr<Calculator>` member. No `memcpy` needed.  If you add more members to `myStruct` the move ops will still do the right thing.