# Is it possible to choose between constructors in main without writing a copy-constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Real example is obviously much longer, but this sums up my problem:

```
class Object
{
 int mInt1,mInt2;
 Object::Object();
 Object::Object(int param1);
 Object::Object(int param1, int param2);
};
Object::Object(){}
Object::Object(int param1):mInt1(param1){}
Object::Object(int param1, int param2):mInt1(param1),mInt1(param2){}
```

Then in main:

```
if (type1){
  Object instance(param1);
}
else{
  Object instance(param1,param2);
}
// do stuff with instance
```

Whoops! That won't work, instance is out of scope for the program that follows.

```
Object instance;
if (type1){
  instance = Object(param1);
}
else{
  instance = Object(param1,param2);
}
// do stuff with instance
```

But now I run in to trouble because I didn't have a copy constructor defined.  I'd really rather not write a copy-constructor because my actual class has dozens of members, many of which are non-basic types and might require even more work to copy.

Specifically, I am getting

```
main.cpp: error: use of deleted function ‘Object& Object::operator=(Object&&)’
         instance = Object(param1);
                  ^
note: ‘Object& Object::operator=(Object&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

Comment: So you really want one constructor to leave one data member un-initialized? I think you need a re-design.

Comment: You can also allocate the `instance` dynamically.

Comment: Everything in your class is `private`?

Comment: @juanchopanza The object represents a simulated system, the same simulation methods apply to systems which have different relevant parameters.

Comment: The pattern of your constructors cries for using default arguments or delegating constructors.

Comment: Can you use a constructor with a default value for parameter 2?

Comment: The usage is of several different types of systems, each characterized by a different parameter set. Of course I could just keep one constructor and move all of the differences into different methods or interpretation of default values but that strikes me as a very roundabout way of accomplishing what I want.

Comment: As I said, I think you need a re-design. This sounds very messy.

Comment: _"But now I run in to trouble because I didn't have a copy constructor defined."_ No, you run in to trouble because you don't have an assignment operator defined. That isn't a copy construction, the clue is that `instance` is already constructed, and you're assigning a new value to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The universal way to deal with non-copyable objects is to throw it into a unique_ptr (or auto_ptr, depending on your compiler).

```
  std::unique_ptr<Object> instance;

  if (type1) {
    instance.reset(new Object(i));
  }
  else {
    instance.reset(new Object(i, j));
  }
```

Using raw pointers here really isn't safe because once you start having to deal with exceptions or any interesting code paths it becomes a chore to worry about leaks.  Trust me, **in 100% of cases, you will have less work and lines of code to deal with if you just drop it in a unique_ptr**.

---

An optimal solution would be to redesign Object's constructors, because circumventing non-copyability may leave the object in an illegal state.  In general, you want to preserve non-copyability if the compiler thinks it's necessary.  We don't have the details here to flesh out such a solution however.

Comment: I like your answer. +1 However, I personally find that warning a little irritating and not really helpful. I would suggest to remove it.

Comment: I reworded it to be less harsh, but I think it's a necessary footnote.  It's design advice, but so is the suggestion to use managed pointers vs raw.  Using pointers to circumvent non-copyability is not safe in general.

Comment: How complex does `Object` have to be before a dynamic memory allocation is faster than default initialization?

Comment: @StuartOlsen Measure, measure, measure. Because it really depends on many factors: operating system, compiler, machine, how busy are other threads with memory allocations, etc. But roughly speaking a memory allocation usually takes more than 100 cycles and is sometimes a bottleneck in tight loops.

Comment: I really don't like to be forced to use a heap allocation when the reason is not that the object will live outside the scope. I found a solution which don't use heap allocation but still allow using the object without making go out of scope. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you do not want dynamically allocation then you can use an Initialize function:

```
class Object
{
 int mInt1,mInt2;
 Object::Object();
 Object::Initialize();
 Object::Initialize(int param1);
 Object::Initialize(int param1, int param2);
};
Object::Object(){Initialize();} //call the empty Initialize for nice coding...:)
Object::Initialize(){  }
Object::Initialize(int param1){ mInt1(param1); }
Object::Initialize(int param1, int param2){ mInt1(param1);mInt1(param2);}
```

Then you can use initialize to select the type.

```
Object instance;
if (type1){
  instance.Initialize(param1);
}
else{
  instance.Initialize(param1,param2);
}
```

Comment: Double intialization is generally very error prone. It's very common in the game industry for example, but it's also a massive source of error because when you get an object you are not sure the initialization function have been called before, and if you want to be sure you have to check it, which is a cost.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a low-level(ish) solution which does what you want. I will leave it up to you to decide whether it's a good idea to use it:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
class MultiInitialiser
{
  T *object;
  std::aligned_storage<T> storage;

public:
  MultiInitialiser() : object(nullptr)
  {}

  template <class... Arg>
  void initialise(Arg &&... arg)
  {
    if (object)
      throw "Double init error";
    object = new (&storage) T(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
  }

  operator T& ()
  { return *object; }

  operator const T& () const
  { return *object; }

  ~MultiInitialiser()
  {
    if (object)
      object->~T();
  }
};
```

Copy/move operations for the above are left as an excercise for the reader ;-)

The class would then be used like this:

```
MultiInitialiser<Object> instance;
if (type1){
  instance.initialise(param1);
}
else{
  instance.initialise(param1,param2);
}
```

Apart from the cast to `T`, you could also give the class `operator*` and `operator->` returning the contained object, similar to what [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/development.html#boost_optional.development.the_interface) does.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options that let you do this while retaining automatic storage, and which one you should use depends on the semantics of the type `Object`.

## The POD

If you have a type like the one given in the question, you might choose to reduce it to a POD type; basically, remove all of the user-provided constructors and give everything the same access specifier:

```
struct Object {
    int mInt1, mInt2;
};
```

Then, your initialization pattern might look like this (using [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax)):

```
Object o; // Default-initialized, a no-op

if (condition)
    new (&o) Object {i};
else
    new (&o) Object {i, j};
```

## General Types

Generally speaking, your typical value-semantic type will work perfectly fine if you default-initialize and then assign, thanks to move semantics:

```
std::vector <foo> v;

if (condition)
    v = std::vector <foo> (42);
else
    v = std::vector <foo> {bar, baz, quux};
```

Often, though, you'll still be doing work in the default constructor, because certain types' default-constructed objects (e.g., `std::vector`) have well-defined state. If you want to avoid this work for an arbitrary predefined type, you might want to use `std::optional` (as of this writing not actually yet standard):

```
std::optional <big_but_flat> b;

if (condition)
    b.emplace (i);
else
    b.emplace (i, j);
```

## Without `std::optional`

You might object that `std::optional` has too much overhead associated with it, and I'll leave it to you and your measurements to decide whether that's the case. At any rate, we *can* get our behaviour without worrying about that overhead— but may the nasal demons have mercy if you don't actually perform your initialization. We'll use a `union` to get what we want:

```
// At function scope
union store_v {
    std::vector <int> v;

    store_v () {}
    ~store_v () { v.~vector <int> (); }
} sv;

if (condition)
    new (&sv.v) std::vector <int> (42);
else
    new (&sv.v) std::vector <int> {49, 343, 2401};
```

This may be improved. For example, we can make the storage a template:

```
template <typename T>
union store {
    T t;

    store () {}
    ~store () { t.~T (); }
};

// At function scope
store <std::vector <int>> sv;
if (condition)
    new (&sv.t) std::vector <int> (42);
else
    new (&sv.t) std::vector <int> {49, 343, 2401};
```

We can give ourselves a reference:

```
template <typename T>
union store {
    T t;

    store () {}
    ~store () { t.~T (); }
};

// At function scope
store <std::vector <int>> sv;
auto&& v = sv.t; // Deduce const, for what that's worth

if (condition)
    new (&v) std::vector <int> (42);
else
    new (&v) std::vector <int> {49, 343, 2401};
```

And with a little attention to detail to avoid name collisions and handle C++'s… interesting declaration syntax, we could even define a couple of macros to clean the code up (implementation left as an exercise to the reader):

```
template <typename T>
union store {
    T t;

    store () {}
    ~store () { t.~T (); }
};

// At function scope
DECL_UNINIT (std::vector <int>, v);

if (condition)
    INIT (v, (42));
else
    INIT (v, {49, 343, 2401});
```

Comment: Instead of using a macro, I'd use a member function like `emplace`. (You'd still have to use some `.get()`, `->`, `.t` or reference to access the stored object, though.)

Comment: @dyp That definitely has an advantage in being a whole lot easier to write correctly. Using the macros, however, has an advantage in that you only need to modify the declaration and initializations to apply this optimization to existing code. As usual, there's a tradeoff, and I think it mostly boils down to how willing you are to wrestle the language into something the preprocessor won't mangle into an unparseable soup. Plus, this is from a correctness-analysis standpoint really ugly hackery however you abstract it. I'd almost rather have the macro just as a warning to tread lightly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pointer to your object and instantiate it by new operator:

```
Object * instance;
if (type1){
  instance = new Object(param1);
}
else{
  instance = new Object(param1,param2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using something that is called **[copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)**.

This states that the compiler **MAY** optimize the code and avoid a copy constructor in such a case.
But it doesn't have to, and may use a copy constructor anyway.

The right way (without being subjected to the whims of the compiler) would be to use a pointer:

```
Object* instance;
if (type1){
  instance = new Object(param1);
}
else{
  instance = new Object(param1,param2);
}
```

Comment: Afaik, the language requires the copy constructor to be accessible when the copy is elided. So, it's not up to the whims of the compiler, but a standardized language feature.

Comment: I'm not sure where the copy elision comes in. But the point is they don't have an accessible assignment operator.

Comment: The OP _doesn't_ use it. Maybe he _should_ though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a move assignment. Depending what your data members look like, you may get away with memcopying some or all of them, cf. [Move constructor with memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789422/move-constructor-with-memcpy).

That said, I assume that either you need a full set of constructors/destructors, including copy and assignment; that will always be necessary if you want to have it in containers, assign it etc. Or else the class doesn't need any of that and you just initialize the needed parts of it depending on the situation, and when you are done, you de-initialize manually.

Comment: The code would need a move assignment operator, not move constructor, and if `memcpy` is a safe implementation then probably so is letting the compiler generate it by using `=default`

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: You are right, I was sloppy; it's an assignment (just corrected). Using the default: I understand that pointers to objects which are deleted in the destructor need to be set to zero in the source of the assignment, so that they are not deleted twice. Does the default move assignment do that? And then there is the idea in the link I gave of grouping memcpyable members so that a big part of the object can be memcpied.

Comment: No, the default implementation won't zero pointers. What is the advantage of using `memcpy` over just assigning members though? If memcpy is the optimum implementation the compiler will do it. The question you linked to (and the accepted answer) are not a good idea, ever.

Answer (score 1):

In your version of one-parameter constructor, the `mInt2` member is just ignored (isn't ever initialized), so I assume that you don't do any computation with that member if `type1` is `false` (though I don't know how you're doing it without storing `type1`).

So, why don't just change the dessign? Make te constructor take `int param1`, `int param2` and `type1` as parameters and choose internally how to build himself:

```
class Object
{
 int mInt1,mInt2;

 Object::Object() :
   mInt1(0), // don't forget to initialize your values!
   mInt2(0)
 {}

 // Object::Object(int param1); no more 1-parameter ctor.

 Object::Object(int param1, int param2, type type1) :
   mInt1(param1),
   mInt2(type1 ? param2 : 0) // assuming that 0 isn't a valid value for mInt2
 {}
};
```

Then in `main`:

```
Object instance(param1, param2, type1);
// do stuff with instance
```

I guess that it looks a little neater.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to do it **without requiring allocating the object on the heap**, using a lambda.
Basically, the idea is to separate the construction from the usage. (the following assume that you fixed the difinition of Object so that it compiles)

```
auto work = []( Object& object ){ 
   // here do the work on the object
};

// now create the object and apply the work in the process:
if (type1){
  Object instance(param1);
  work( instance );
}
else{
  Object instance(param1,param2);
  work( instance );
}
```

Here no copy  was involved but the same code is still applied whatever the wy the object was constructed, and without having to declare an external function (as a lambda is a local function).
From the memory point of view, there will always be only one instance object so the stack memory allocated will always be the same size whatever the path.

Obviously, this don't work if the instance have to get out of the scope of the whole function. If it's the case, then you really need to allocate it on the heap using a smart pointer preferably.